# Sidebar server component layout next js 13

Tags: next.js13

I created a driver folder, On the folder i have layout, page and users. I want a sidebar on the layout. The sidebar is working well but i want toggle menu for open and closing the sidebar. I have a error because im on the server component. If i use 'use client' is working well. But i want to put the sidebar on the layout with button in server component. If I use 'use client' he take more ressources to take the data. Any solutions. Or i continue with 'use client' in layout. Thanks for you help

Layout.js :
[1] : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/assets/71132716/b3915d60-ece7-4c89-901c-61820dc15900

users.js
[2] : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/assets/71132716/2966ec57-ee8f-4287-afb1-6c481bc6e835

page.js :

[3] : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/assets/71132716/3cc548d8-c833-4864-b69c-c81c6117a117

I want put the button here :
[4] : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/assets/71132716/fde00ea1-5a57-49c1-8104-398eb447ab60

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> But i want to put the sidebar on the layout with button in server component.

> ....i want toggle menu for open and closing the sidebar

> If i use 'use client' is working well.

**Solution :**

You should continue using `use client` because interactivity and event listeners should be handled client side, while other activities like fetch data, access backend, etc. then this should be done server-side.

***Please read :***

- **When to use Server and Client Components? :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#when-to-use-server-and-client-components
- **Client Components :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#benefits-of-client-rendering
- **Server Components :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#benefits-of-server-rendering